# UPME (User Profiles Made Easy) Profile Fields in Template

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to display only certain fields from the User Profiles Made Easy Plugin on my page. The users 'Display Name' for example, I don't need the full profile, just the display name. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

I have looked at the docs, posted on the plugin forum and trawled the Internet for help but I can't find any.

Currently I can only get the whole profile to display, even when I pass the display_name in.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[upme view=display_name]"); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish this using the following code:

```
<?php 
    $display_name = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'display_name');
    $description = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'description');
?>
```

Then I pulled the value from the array using:

```
<?php echo $display_name[0]; ?>
```

I am no php expert so I am not sure if this is efficient (or even correct), but it seemed to work for me.